# spring boot is executing data.sql and schema.sql twice?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, h2, spring-test

I was trying to test a Spring Boot Application. I am using an in-memory H2 DB that I would like to initialize with some data and implement an integration test by comparing the number of data in the database after I have added one element in the project table but the test is failing and when I try to track the execution the data.sql and schema.sql are executed two times.

test class

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes=ProjectManagementApplication.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@SqlGroup(@Sql( executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts= {"classpath:schema.sql","classpath:data.sql"}))
public class ProjectRepositoryIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    ProjectRepository proRepo;
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository empRepo;
    @Test
    public void ifNewProjectSaved_thenSuccess() {
        Project newProject=new Project("new Project","COMPLETED","test Description");
        proRepo.save(newProject);
        List<Project> pro= proRepo.findAll();
        for(int i=0;i<pro.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(pro.get(i));
        }
        assertEquals(5,pro.size());
    }

}
```

schema file

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS employee_seq;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (

employee_id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('employee_seq') PRIMARY KEY,
first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL


);

CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS project_seq;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS project (

project_id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('project_seq') PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
stage VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL

);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee_project (

project_id BIGINT REFERENCES project, 
employee_id BIGINT REFERENCES employee

);
```

data.sql

```
-- INSERT EMPLOYEES         
insert into employee (employee_id, first_name, lastname, email) values (nextval('employee_seq'), 'John', 'Warton', 'warton@gmail.com');
insert into employee (employee_id, first_name, lastname, email) values (nextval('employee_seq'), 'Mike', 'Lanister', 'lanister@gmail.com');
insert into employee (employee_id, first_name, lastname, email) values (nextval('employee_seq'), 'Steve', 'Reeves', 'Reeves@gmail.com');
insert into employee (employee_id, first_name, lastname, email) values (nextval('employee_seq'), 'Ronald', 'Connor', 'connor@gmail.com');
insert into employee (employee_id, first_name, lastname, email) values (nextval('employee_seq'), 'Jim', 'Salvator', 'Sal@gmail.com');
insert into employee (employee_id, first_name, lastname, email) values (nextval('employee_seq'), 'Peter', 'Henley', 'henley@gmail.com');
insert into employee (employee_id, first_name, lastname, email) values (nextval('employee_seq'), 'Richard', 'Carson', 'carson@gmail.com');
insert into employee (employee_id, first_name, lastname, email) values (nextval('employee_seq'), 'Honor', 'Miles', 'miles@gmail.com');
insert into employee (employee_id, first_name, lastname, email) values (nextval('employee_seq'), 'Tony', 'Roggers', 'roggers@gmail.com');

-- INSERT PROJECTS          
insert into project (project_id, name, stage, description) values (nextval('project_seq'), 'Large Production Deploy', 'NOTSTARTED', 'This requires all hands on deck for the final deployment of the software into production');
insert into project (project_id, name, stage, description) values (nextval('project_seq'), 'New Employee Budget',  'COMPLETED', 'Decide on a new employee bonus budget for the year and figureout who will be promoted');
insert into project (project_id, name, stage, description) values (nextval('project_seq'), 'Office Reconstruction', 'INPROGRESS', 'The office building in Monroe has been damaged due to hurricane in the region. This needs to be reconstructed');
insert into project (project_id, name, stage, description) values (nextval('project_seq'), 'Improve Intranet Security', 'INPROGRESS', 'With the recent data hack, the office security needs to be improved and proper security team needs to be hired for implementation');

-- INSERT PROJECT_EMPLOYEE_RELATION
insert into employee_project (employee_id, project_id) (select e.employee_id, p.project_id from employee e, project p where e.lastname ='Warton' AND p.name = 'Large Production Deploy');
insert into employee_project (employee_id, project_id) (select e.employee_id, p.project_id from employee e, project p where e.lastname ='Warton' AND p.name = 'New Employee Budget');
insert into employee_project (employee_id, project_id) (select e.employee_id, p.project_id from employee e, project p where e.lastname ='Warton' AND p.name = 'Office Reconstruction');
insert into employee_project (employee_id, project_id) (select e.employee_id, p.project_id from employee e, project p where e.lastname ='Reeves' AND p.name = 'Large Production Deploy');
insert into employee_project (employee_id, project_id) (select e.employee_id, p.project_id from employee e, project p where e.lastname ='Warton' AND p.name = 'New Employee Budget');
insert into employee_project (employee_id, project_id) (select e.employee_id, p.project_id from employee e, project p where e.lastname ='Warton' AND p.name = 'Improve Intranet Security');
insert into employee_project (employee_id, project_id) (select e.employee_id, p.project_id from employee e, project p where e.lastname ='Henley' AND p.name = 'Office Reconstruction');
insert into employee_project (employee_id, project_id) (select e.employee_id, p.project_id from employee e, project p where e.lastname ='Henley' AND p.name = 'Improve Intranet Security');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot's`DataSource` initialization will apply `classpath:schema.sql` and `classpath:data.sql` files automatically without using `@SqlGroup` and `@Sql` on your test class.

You should either remove `@SqlGroup` and `@Sql` from your test class or disable `DataSource` initialization. To achieve the latter set `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never` (Spring Boot 2.4 and earlier) or `spring.sql.init.mode=never` (Spring Boot 2.5 and later).

Comment: Or use Flyway instead.